# Iterating and printing a JSON with no initial key and multiple entries

Tags: javascript, json

How would you go about iterating through a JSON object no initial key but multiple entries?

```
var json_no_key = 

{
            {"txid" : "1",
             "amount" : "100",},

             {"txid" : "2",
             "amount" : "50"},

};
```

I have tried using other methods whereby each element would have a key itself such as

```
for(var i = 0; i < transaction.vin.length; i++)
{
    var my_json = transaction.vin[i];

   console.log(my_json[i])

    for(var j = 0; j < my_json.length; j++)
    {
        console.log(my_json[j]);
    }
}
```

but this relies on there being an initial key.

The reasoning for this format is due to the nature of how a api outputs data.

Comment: That's simply not valid JSON or JavaScript in the first place. You cannot have an object with values without keys, like you show in your example code. That would make sense only with an array (but then it would have `[ ]` and not `{ }`). If it were an array, you could just do `for (const obj of json_no_key) { console.log(obj.txid, obj.amount) }` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I echo with @CherryDT. The object `json_no_key` is not a valid JSON format. Please check the format in https://jsonlint.com/. Instead of an object, convert it into an array so that you could do the following using a simple `forEach`:

```js
const a =[
    {
        "txid": "1",
        "amount": "100",
    },

    {
        "txid": "2",
        "amount": "50"
    },

];

a.forEach(element=>{
  console.log(element.txid);
  console.log(element.amount);

})
```